# SSIS Case Statement not working

Tags: sql-server, ssis, expression, etl

This SSIS case expression looks perfectly valid to me, but it's coming up red. Can anybody explain why?

```
[Copy of "final_benefit_type_grouper"] == "MEDICAL" ? "2"
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably because you don't have the " : {ELSE} " part of the expression.   What do you want the value to be if the column does not equal "MEDICAL"?

Answer (score 1):

Referring to the *Microsoft Documentation*, `?` conditional syntax is like the following:

```
boolean_expression?expression1:expression2
```

*"If the Boolean expression evaluates to TRUE, then the first expression is evaluated and the result is the expression result. If the Boolean expression evaluates to FALSE then the second expression is evaluated and its result is the expression result."* *[Read more](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/expressions/conditional-ssis-expression)*

so i think you are missing the second part of the expression, i might be something like this:

```
[Copy of "final_benefit_type_grouper"] == "MEDICAL" ? "2" : ""
```

Also it is better to add a `NULL` checking to your expression using *[ISNULL()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/expressions/isnull-ssis-expression)* function *(to avoid a null value exception)*:

```
ISNULL([Copy of "final_benefit_type_grouper"])? "" : ( [Copy of "final_benefit_type_grouper"] == "MEDICAL" ? "2" : "")
```

*It is also to follow this [Link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/48372e18-598b-4005-9ed8-7ccc8bba30ae/how-to-write-case-statement-in-ssis-expression-using-derived-column-transformation-available-in-bi?forum=sqlintegrationservices) to Read more about write a case statment using a SSIS expression*